# If Thickbox is opened set body noscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, thickbox

My JS/jQuery knowledge is very basic so I'm asking for a bit of help here.

I'm trying to achieve something like a Pinterest effect with Thickbox.

What I'm assuming should happen is using JS or jQuery to monitor Thickbox actions (if #TB_window is present or not) and apply the following rules:

- If Thickbox is opened -> set body style to overflow: hidden
- Else Thickbox is closed -> set body style to overflow: auto

I'm using the integrated into WordPress Thickbox with the function - add_thickbox(); if it makes any difference.

Comment: are you using [this](http://codylindley.com/thickbox/)?

Comment: Yes, but the one build into WordPress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure as to the construct of the page but the following code should fix it with a little tweaking

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.element').click(function(){
        $('.body').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
    });
    $('.overlay, .close-button').click(function(){
        $('body').css({'overflow':'visible'});
    });
});
```

**Just replace the following with the correct class names**

*.element* - the class of the clickable link or image that opens the Thickbox
*.overlay* - the class of the semi-transparent overlay behind the Thickbox
*.close-button* - if needed, the class of the close button on the Thickbox

Comment: With a few tweaks this almost works. When clicked it assigns overflow hidden to the body. But the problems is that the Thickbox content is called within an iframe and the content inside the iframe has body tag (and everything) and when the hide/close button is clicked the body tag within the iframe gets overflow: auto, not the actual body tag on the page. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I would say the easiest way of solving this would be adding a class to your page's body tag and changing $('body') to $('.body-class'), hopefully this should solve the issue!

Comment: Still no luck. I think the problem might be in using $(document).ready(function()) because the iframe is loaded after this class so it doesn't take the newly added ids and classes from Thickbox. But what else should I use?

Comment: As it turns out there are quite a few alternatives to Thickbox some of which had these functions build into them... Using Colorbox for example there are functions that trigger on Open, Load, Complete, Cleanup and Closed. So using the method mentioned above I was able to do exactly what I wanted with a code like this:

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".colorbox").colorbox({
     onOpen:function(){ $( '#main-body' ).addClass( 'noscroll' ); },
     onClosed:function(){ $( '#main-body' ).removeClass( 'noscroll' ); }
    });
   });`