# Disable body scroll in offcanvas (bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Working with a fixed offcanvas menu. Cannot seem to disable body scroll when it is active in ios. The concept is simple, `overflow-y:auto;` in the offcanvas fixed menu and `overflow:hidden;` in the body. Is this possible to do with jquery instead of relying on the CSS? and what is be better to do this in jquery, eg: prevent default or something?

Jquery (offcanvas):

```
$('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
  $('.offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
  $( "body" ).addClass( ".offcanvas-body" ); //Here not working! 
  $(".nav.nav-pills").toggleClass('nav nav-pills').addClass( "nav navbar-nav" );
  $(".subnavbar.headroom.navbar-default.subnavbar-fixed-top.hidden-xs.hidden-sm").removeClass("subnavbar headroom navbar-default subnavbar-fixed-top hidden-xs hidden-sm").addClass("navmenu navmenu-default hidden-md hidden-lg" );
  });
```

Here is CSS class:

```
.offcanvas-body {
overflow: hidden!important;
}
```

Using `$( "html" ).addClass( ".offcanvas-body" );` works in a desktop browsers but fails in ios and tablets. Any direction on this one would be appreciated.

Comment: I've started a similar question a while back, see if i'd help you out http://stackoverflow.com/q/20916086/1419575

Answer (score 0):

I ended up binding the touchmove event and then unbinding it in a setInterval but there is probably a better method.

```
function removeMobileScroll (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
setInterval(function() {
    if ($('.navmenu').hasClass('in')) {
        $('body').bind('touchmove', removeMobileScroll);
    }
        else {
    $('body').unbind('touchmove', removeMobileScroll);
    }
}, 100);
```